# Modify emailed reports content

Tags: reports, scheduled-job, system-workflow-messages

I'd like to get users more in tune with their data by sending them notifications of certain high-value reports. I really don't want them with the data attached in a PDF or worse, a CSV. I'd rather just have the report link by itself (it already does this).

How can I remove the attachment option altogether?

Perhaps more importantly, how can I modify the email template so I can add some message content directly into the report email itself (not in the PDF attachment). What template is this using? I'd just want to hard-code some text that would apply to all reports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
Since 5.29 you can do this in an extension do like the override example at https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_alterReportVar

In the extension's main file example.php:

```
function example_civicrm_alterReportVar($varType, &$var, $reportForm) {
  switch ($varType) {
    case 'outputhandlers':
      $var['\CRM_Report_OutputHandler_Pdf'] = '\My\Namespace\PdfOutputHandler';
      break;
  }
}
```

and then in \My\Namespace\PdfOutputHandler something like:

```
namespace My\Namespace;
use CRM_Example_ExtensionUtil as E;
class PdfOutputHandler extends \CRM_Report_OutputHandler_Pdf {

  // Override to remove the attachment
  public function getFileName(): string {
    return '';
  }

  // This is similar to the default output but we replace the "file is attached" text. Adjust more as desired.
  // For reference the default is at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/1f0a905a1a90e3bb68f0492022c488eab1ed3f82/CRM/Report/OutputHandler/Pdf.php#L52-L56
  public function getMailBody(): string {    
    $url = CRM_Utils_System::url('civicrm/report/instance/' . $this->getForm()->getID(), 'reset=1', TRUE);
    return $this->getForm()->getReportHeader() . '<p>' . ts('Report URL') .
      ": {$url}</p>" . '<p>' .
      ts('Here is my text I want to add.') . '</p>' .
      $this->getForm()->getReportFooter();
  }
}
```

---

**OLDER ANSWER FOR OLDER VERSIONS:**

The email body content starts here for csv: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.18.4/CRM/Report/Form.php#L3413, and a bit lower down for pdf.

Note also the attachments are hardcoded in, a couple lines lower down.

Note that in the report itself on the Title and Format tab you can add some text/html at the end of the header which will get included in the email.

The code seems to be after hook_civicrm_alterReportVar so I don't think you can use that to remove the attachments, but you should be able to use hook_civicrm_alterMailParams to remove the attachments.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably just make a separate cron script that emails them the links and whatever text you want, i.e. not using the scheduled report task just a plain cron script. If you want to send to a civi group or something like that then the cron script could be a `cv` script and then use the civi api inside the script.

Comment: I need to stick to the civireport email functionality + scheduled job. I have a simple use case and just need to find the template to add text.

Comment: Ok, have added another answer.

Answer (score 1):

We use the 'Title and Format' tab as Demerit mentions above and have stuck some text/html in the 'Report Header' box. To avoid attachments going out with them went with the below parameters for the scheduled job.
instanceId=x
format=print
Not a global solution but may be suitable if results aren't too large.